# How many TFS 2010 Service Accounts for This Topology?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, team-foundation-server, service-accounts

I am a newbie on this stuff.

I want to create an environment consist of TFS Server (App&Build), Sharepoint2010, and SQL Server. the TFS server are interacting continuously with three servers : Production, Test, and Development. how many groups should I create? how many service accounts should I create?

I need your recommendation and analysis, please
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you use the standard TFS 2010 installation option, you can do the entire installation and you will only need to create a single domain account. Make sure it has Allow log on locally permission. TFS will prompts you for it during install. TFS will use it for both report reader and sharepoint farm admin identity. All other service accounts can be set to Network service.

More information on TFS service accounts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578625.aspx